# Case subquery returning too many rows within where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi what I am trying to achieve is a query which has a dynamic column name in the where clause depending on whether a column is null or not.

So as an example, if a row has an Appointment Date which is not null, the where clause will be:

```
WHERE `Building ID` = '1' and `Appointment Date`='2013-10-10' ;
```

And if the Appointment Date is null, the where clause will be:

```
WHERE `Building ID` = '1' and `Backup Date`='2013-10-10' ;
```

Right now my subquery in the where clause is returning too many rows so the query fails, how should I get around this issue?

My query is below:

```
SELECT `Job ID` 
FROM jobs 
WHERE `Building ID` = '1' 
and (select case when `Appointment Date` IS NOT NULL THEN `Appointment Date` 
else `Backup Date` end FROM jobs WHERE `Building ID` = '1') = '2013-10-10'
```

Comment: you can use `LIMIT` like this: `select case when Appointment Date IS NOT NULL THEN Appointment Date 
else Backup Date end FROM jobs WHERE Building ID = '1' LIMIT 1)`

Comment: Is the Building ID unique? I think you have multiple Building IDs in a table. Otherwise it shouldn't return more than 1 row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `Job ID` 
FROM jobs 
WHERE `Building ID` = '1' 
and case when `Appointment Date` IS NOT NULL 
         then `Appointment Date` = '2013-10-10' 
         else `Backup Date` = '2013-10-10'
    end
```

Comment: Great thanks, getting rid of the subquery has got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `COALESCE()` function. It returns the first of its parameters which is not null.

```
WHERE `Customer ID` = '1' and COALESCE(`Appointment Date`, `Backup Date`) ='2013-10-10' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT `Job ID` 
FROM jobs 
WHERE `Building ID` = '1' 
AND ((`Appointment Date` IS NOT NULL AND `Appointment Date` = '2013-10-10') 
      OR
     (`Appointment Date` IS NULL AND `Backup Date` = '2013-10-10'))
```